# How do I pass module.exports in my index.js / discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I made a "mute" and "warn" command for my discord bot and when I try to run them I get an error. This error is because in all my previous commands I used ".execute(message, args)" in my command code, so when I wanted to get the command from my index.js I just had to pass `client.commands.get('name').execute(message, args)`. Now, I don't have this in my command, so how do I get it from index.js. I hope you understand what I'm saying.

Here's index.js:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client, Collection } = require ('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'TOKEN';
const PREFIX = '-';

const fs = require('fs');
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
 
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('Compass is online');
    client.user.setActivity('GameCore', {type: 'WATCHING'}).catch(console.error);
})

client.on('message', message=>{
    
    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;
    else {
        const args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).split(/ +/);
        const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

        if(command === 'help') {
            client.commands.get('help').execute(message, args);
        }
        if(command === 'kick') {
            client.commands.get('kick').execute(message, args);
        }
        if(command === 'ban') {
            client.commands.get('ban').execute(message, args);  
        }
        if(command === 'slowmode') {
            client.commands.get('slowmode').execute(message, args);  
        }
        if(command === 'warn') {
            client.commands.get('warn').execute(message, args);  
        }
        if(command === 'mute') {
            client.commands.get('mute').execute(message, args);  
        }


    }
})

client.login(token);
```

mute.js (warn.js is build in a similar format):

```
var Discord = require('discord.js');
var ms = require('ms');

module.export = async(message, args) => {
    if(!message.member.hasPemission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return message.channel.send(':x:***You do not have permissions to run this command!***')

    var user = message.mentions.users.first();
    if(!user) return message.channel.send(':x:***Please mention a user!***')

    var member;

    try {
        member = await message.guild.members.fetch(user);
    
    } catch(err) {
        member = null;
    }

    if(!member) return message.channel.send(':x:***Please mention a user!***');
    if(member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return message.channel.send(':x:***You cannot mute that person!***')

    var rawTime = args[1];
    var time = ms(rawTime)
    if(!time) return message.channel.send('You didn\'t specify a time!')
    
    var reason = args.splice(2).join(' ');
    if(!reason) return message.reply('You need to give a mute reason!');
    
    var channel = message.guild.channels.catch.find(c => c.name === 'potato');

    var log = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(':white_check_mark:***This user has been muted.***')
    .addField('User:', user, true)
    .addField('By:', message.author, true)
    .addField('Expires:', rawTime)
    .addField('Reason:', reason)
    channel.send(log);

    var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('You have been muted!')
    .addField('Expires:', rawTime, true)
    .addField('Reason:', reason, true);

    try {
        user.send(embed);
    } catch(err) {
        console.warn(err);
    }

    var role = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Muted');

    member.roles.add(role);

    setTimeout(async() => {
        member.roles.remove(role);
    }, time);

    message.channel.send(`**${user}** has been muted by **${message.author}** for **${rawTime}**!`)
}
```

And the error I get when I type "-mute" or "-warn":

```
            client.commands.get('mute').execute(message, args);
                                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (G:\Alexis\Desktop\Compass\index.js:46:40)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (G:\Alexis\Desktop\Compass\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (G:\Alexis\Desktop\Compass\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (G:\Alexis\Desktop\Compass\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (G:\Alexis\Desktop\Compass\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (G:\Alexis\Desktop\Compass\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (G:\Alexis\Desktop\Compass\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (G:\Alexis\Desktop\Compass\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:797:20)
```

Answer (score 0):

When exporting module you should use `module.exports` instead of `module.export`.

Also you are now trying to read `name`and `command` properties from your module but there is none.

```
const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
client.commands.set(command.name, command);
```

So if you want to use approach like this your command module should look something like this:

```
module.exports.name = 'mute';
module.exports.command = async (message, args) { ... };
```

or you can use your file name and export only function from your module

in `index.js`

```
const path = require('path');

...

for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
 
    client.commands.set(path.parse(file).name, command);
}

...
```

and in `mute.js`

```
...

module.exports = async (message, args) => { ... };
```

Learn basics of nodejs modules from https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/nodejs-module-exports